# Unwrapping gives out the wrong symmetry

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

When I was working on UVs of the lotus flower, I noticed that the some of the vertices are not aligned well when unwrapping, because of the rotations I made in the 3D viewport. For example, if I try to rotate a cube 45 degrees, then uv will not only rotate, the vertices are being unaligned when unwrapping. And at the same time, three of the vertices were pinned by me by having the top vertice 1, middle .05 and bottom 0 and are all aligned in the x-axis. And still the vertices are unaligned next time I've unwrapped it. For example the left vertice recieved the cords of U: 0.653 & V: 0.445, while the right vertice got U: 0.653 & V: 0.455 instead. Can someone help me and explain why the rotations ALSO effects in UV-Editor?

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add some images to your post? So it's easier to understand. Thank you.